# player A speak truth 4 out of 9 times . A card is drawn from pack of 52 cards ,

Tags: probability

Player A tells the truth $4$ out of $9$ times. A card is drawn from pack of $52$ cards, and A reports that there is diamond. What is probability that actually there was a diamond?

Probability of truth is $4/9$ probability of lie is $5/9$ 
Probability that he reported there is diamond is $$\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{13}{52}+\frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{39}{52} = \frac{19}{36}$$
Applying Bayes' theorem, the probability of actual diamond is:
$$\frac{\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{13}{52}}{\frac{19}{36}}$$
I don't know if I'm right or wrong, can anyone verify it? Thanks in advance

Comment: $(4/9)(13/52)+(5/9)(39/52)=(4/9)(1/4)+(5/9)(3/4)=19/36$, not $13/36$.

Answer (score -1):

If a Diamond is reported, one of two things happened.  Diamond+truth or Other+lie.

Those probabilities are $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{4}{9}$ and $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{5}{9}$ or $\frac{1}{9}$ and $\frac{5}{12}$

Thus the probability of it actually being a diamond would be $$\frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{5}{12}}=\frac{4}{19}$$

I think your (4/9)(13/52)+(5/9)(39/52) calculation was incorrect.

Comment: thank u   it was typing mistake I i want to Know that is my concept is right ?

Comment: Yes, your concept is correct.

Comment: The case "other+lie" includes the probability that it was a spade and he reports clubs. However, this shouldn't count as part of the probability of reporting diamond.

Comment: Ah. I read "Reported there is a diamond" as kind of a Yes/No thing. "It's a diamond!" or "It's not a diamond" with those 4:5 odds. If that is not the case and the person could say anything, then my calculations are indeed incorrect.